# How do I set up my UIViewController to avoid drawing in the notch and bottom slidebar areas?

Tags: ios, layout, uiviewcontroller, iphone-x

I'm resurrurecting an app that I wrote in 2015, and it still works full-screen, but I'm busting my head trying to figure out how to avoid drawing in the notch area and bottom slidebar area on iPhone X and its descendents.

Here's what it looks like on the iPhone 14 Pro Max (in the iOS Simulator).  Note that it's drawing all the way up into the pill area:

[image: My app leaks content into the notch area and bottom area]

My launch screen View Controller Scene has the following properties in the Xcode editor.

- Interface Builder Document

  - Builds for: Deployment Target (12.0)
  - Use Trait Variations: ON
  - Use Safe Area Layout Guides: ON
  - Use as Launch Screen: ON
- View

  - Arrange: Position View
  - Layout: Autoresizing Mask
  - Layout Margins: Default

    - Preserve Superview Margins: OFF
    - Follow Readable width: OFF
    - Safe Area Relative Margins: OFF
  - Layout Guides

    - Safe Area: ON
    - Keyboard: OFF

My Main View Controller Scene has the following properties:

- Interface Builder Document

  - Builds for: Deployment Target (12.0)
  - Use Trait Variations: OFF
  - Use Safe Area Layout Guides: ON
  - Use as Launch Screen: OFF
- View Controller

  - Layout

    - Adjust Scroll View Inserts: ON
    - Hide Bottom Bar on Push: OFF
    - Resize View from NIB: ON
    - Use Full Screen (Deprecated): OFF
  - Extend Edges

    - Under Top Bars: OFF
    - Under Bottom Bars: OFF
    - Under Opaque Bars: OFF

What I'd like instead is for my UIViewController's frame to be automatically limited to just the "safe" area of the screen, which would be the area *between* the notch/pill area and the bottom slidebar area.

Everything looks good on iPhone 8 and on all the iPads. Just having trouble with the recent iPhones.

Comment: It sounds like you have your UI elements constrained to the **view** ... they need to be constrained to the **safe area**.

Comment: @DonMag — Exactly! Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any detailed tutorial or description yet of how to go about doing that. Is it possible to do via the Xcode storyboard editor or the launch screen? Or does it need to be done programmatically in code?

Comment: When you talk about "Interface Builder Document" ... are you using Storyboard? Or individual XIB files?

Comment: @DonMag — I've just got basically a empty Storyboard to establish the startup. There's only one view controller, and I populate it programmatically from `MainViewController.m`. No segues and no other view controllers except the main one.

Comment: Update your question with your relevant code showing how you setup the constraints of your views in your view controller.

Answer (score 1):

This is ***very basic*** auto-layout. You would benefit yourself to read the docs and go through some tutorials.

But, a really quick example, using stack views to get a layout similar to the image you posted:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.95 alpha:1.0];
    
    // we're going to add 6 views in a 2x3 layout
    NSArray <UIColor *>*colors = @[
        [UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor],
        [UIColor cyanColor], [UIColor yellowColor], [UIColor orangeColor],
    ];
    
    UIStackView *sv = [UIStackView new];
    sv.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
    sv.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually;
    sv.spacing = 8.0;
    
    int cIdx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        UIStackView *sv2 = [UIStackView new];
        sv2.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
        sv2.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillEqually;
        sv2.spacing = 8.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            UIView *v = [UIView new];
            v.backgroundColor = colors[cIdx];
            v.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0;
            cIdx++;
            [sv2 addArrangedSubview:v];
        }
        [sv addArrangedSubview:sv2];
    }

    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:sv];
    
    // respect safe area
    UILayoutGuide *g = [self.view safeAreaLayoutGuide];

    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [sv.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.topAnchor constant:0.0],
        [sv.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.leadingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [sv.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.trailingAnchor constant:0.0],
        [sv.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:g.bottomAnchor constant:0.0],
    ]];
    
}

@end
```

Result on an iPhone SE (no notch or virtual home button):

[image]

rotated:

[image]

and on an iPhone 14 Pro:

[image]

[image]